# Razor fails to render view due to weird compilation error CS0234

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have an existing ASP.NET core 2.2 (SDK version 2.2.108) Web API and I'm now adding MVC to host a web page with a controller. I've added:
- the new controller
- the new .cshtml view 
- made sure my startup.cs contains `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);`

I'm using Http.Sys and I get 500 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump] ProcessRequestAsync. 
If I enable exceptions in VS 2017 (15.9.13) I see:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: 'One or more compilation failures occurred:
310z1p4f.mzl(4,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
310z1p4f.mzl(5,40): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
310z1p4f.mzl(4,82): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
310z1p4f.mzl(4,122): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported`

and it continues.

I see in the build output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll
```

I followed several different discussions on SO and github:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908353/5048049
- https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542
- [The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616394/the-type-or-namespace-name-mvc-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-a/35617395)
- [The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825242/the-type-or-namespace-name-hosting-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft)
- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/8880

but no luck. Ideas?

Comment: I made a demo to test , but there is no error thrown .Did  you try to update the last version of ASP.NET core 2.2 SDK  ?

Comment: I'm on that SDK since I want to use VS2017. However I just found the culprit, I write an answer in case somebody else hits the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. Basically, there are two projects:

1. a console app which can be also run as a Windows service . This instantiate the web server
2. a library which contains the Web API

Both were targeting `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, once I've changed 2 to use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and to be a library not console app, everything started working.

It took me a long time to figure this out, since the Web API was working fine before with that (wrong) configuration. meh!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Try this right click your project and edit your project file.

under project reference you should see

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" 
    PrivateAssets="All" />
```

if you do not add it.